# Is possible Move Up Layout?

Tags: android

I would like to do it. This is iOS app 
The entire screen went up and the keyboard was below the buttons

**before displaying the keyboard:**
[image]

**after displaying the keyboard**

[image]

The option "adjustPan" in adroid manifes not work like it, the buttons below of Edittext  hide under keyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`adjustResize` should work for when you want to move the screen up.

https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility.html

Comment: adjustResize crushes components for all stay on the screen, I need something like this to move it up

Comment: What is your layout like? Try wrapping it inside a scrollview and see if it still crushes the layout.